# Automatically bootstrap Angular app injected into web app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use Angular within an existing non-Angular webapp, injecting the app into the page and binding to a particular div. Since the app might require multiple Angular apps to be bound to different divs (showing and hiding them as necessary), it seems I can't use ngApp and must do manual bootstrapping. However, this requires doing something ugly like below, where I have to define a boostrap function, which I call from the app I inject the Angular app into. Is there a way to avoid having to call doBootstrap in this scenario? I'd basically like to inject and start the app automatically. This doesn't happen on initial load, so document.ready style solutions aren't an option. Also, it would be great to avoid having to define an ng-controller on the div, but that's a lesser issue.

```
angular.module('TestApp', [])
.controller('TestAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText = 'testing';
}]);

var doBootstrap = function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myDiv'), ['TestApp']);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I should just have been running the manual bootstrap code after defining the module (i.e. remove the function wrapping it).

```
angular.module('TestApp', [])
.controller('TestAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText = 'testing';
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myDiv'), ['TestApp']);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(document, ['TestApp']);
});
```

Refer to this documentation also: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Angular app needs to be loaded in response to certain events, so document.ready isn't really an option as the document will already be loaded by the time the Angular JS is injected.